# EF - altering FK relationships with Fluent Api without dropping DB?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've run into the situation many times where I have to add or alter a FK relationship to a code-first migrated database.  Take, for example, this model:

```
public sealed class Post : ITenantData {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Tenant` `EntityTypeConfiguration`, I have the following:

```
        HasMany(c => c.Posts)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.TenantId);
```

This is working as I'd expect - the `TenantId` column of `Posts` is used when I query `Tenant.Posts`.

But now I want to add a virtual property from the `Post` to the `Tenant`, altering the above model to the following:

```
public sealed class Post : ITenantData {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant {get; set; }
}
```

I update the `Post` `EntityTypeConfiguration`:

```
       HasRequired(c => c.Tenant)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.TenantId);
```

And hit `update-database`.  I get an error:

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name
>   'IX_TenantId' already exists on table 'dbo.Post'.

In the output, I see this (among other things):

```
 CREATE INDEX [IX_TenantId] ON [dbo].[Post]([TenantId])
```

Followed by the stacktrace.  This isn't a huge deal right now because the app is in development and I can just kill the db.  Obviously I can't do that in production.  How can I perform this simple change via migrations without dropping the db?

Comment: Did you mean Update-Database or Migrate-Database? Are you using automatic or manual migration? Have you tried -Force option ? If scripting did you consider adding the SQL drop index for the index EF is trying to create?

Comment: @philsoady - Sorry, update-database.  Automatic migration.  I have tried -force.  I'm not scripting, relying 100% on EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using Automatic Migrations and even if you are using

```
public class MyMigrationConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext  : DbContext{

    protected  MyMigrationConfiguration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update

    }
}
```

There are some changes that will require a manual script.
Indexes is one of those nasty areas.

I have sqlscripts to delete indexes handy.

The scenario you have looks to me as a "drop index" script then run automatic migrations.
Manual migrations are more painful.   But once you are live and you plan to make ongoing changes you will be glad to have you that approach.

Having said that. It is possible to stay with automatic and just tweak DB with manual script prior.